# .NET SOAP communication with separate certificates for signing and encryption

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I try to configure client communicating with SOAP service written in Java, yet I failed so far. While it's pretty easy to connect with that service using SoapUI (I just need to put these two certificates in adequate places and it just works) it's pretty far from being easy (and intuitive) in C#.

Service uses two different certificates - one for signing message (binary token) and one for TLS encryption. I implemented my own classes for that thing using this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-use-separate-x-509-certificates-for-signing-and-encryption

Thanks to that I'm able to connect and send request, but that's not the end of the problems. Next error was "The incoming message was signed with a token which was different from what used to encrypt the body.  This was not expected."

According to my research I should just erase whole Security header and configure my client to allow unsecured response. Therefore I should implement my own MessageEncoder what I actually did using this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-custom-text-encoder

I only added one extra function that should erase security header, just like @nuronce did in this thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/16de05ed-3776-40e5-b576-139603e4b374/the-incoming-message-was-signed-with-a-token-which-was-different-from-what-used-to-encrypt-the-body?forum=wcf

But that's still not the end of the problems... Right now it says: "The message version of the outgoing message (Soap11 (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/) AddressingNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)) does not match that of the encoder (Soap12 (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) Addressing10 (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing)). Make sure the binding is configured with the same version as the message."

That's weird because in every place with MessageVersion property in my custom encoder classes it's set to MessageVersion.Soap11 as default value that should not be modified, because I don't change anything in my CustomTextMessageEncodingBindingSection.

For every solution WCF gives me another problem and I'm losing my patience for that, because these solutions are not so easy to find and adjust to my needs. I'm also pretty sure that even if I go through my current problem - I will find another one, maybe harder or even impossible to resolve.

Are there other .NET libraries that will allow me to use two different certificates by default and save my code from growing, hard to understand convolutions? And if there is none, how can I deal with WCF?

Comment: Having to deal with the exact same thing right now, are at the custom encoder step and wondering whether to continue down this path... How did you end up solving the problem? What authentication mode did you use (`MutualCertificate` or one of the duplex bindindgs)?

Comment: Actually I never resolved it. We made a proxy service written in Java that would receive JSON requests through REST, translate it to double certificate SOAP and send it over. The other person that was asking me the same question not long ago was stuck the same way, but he ended writing SOAP service in C++. I suppose it's just impossible without basically writing your own WCF. I would give it up and just write it in C++, Java or any other language having libraries with such capability.

Comment: Thanks for your summary. We hacked WCF enough for it to be able to sign and encrypt messages so that the other side accepts them, and decrypt the reply we get. The missing bit is the ability to verify sender's signature... but we can live with that if there's really no reasonable way of doing that.

Comment: @Dav would you be able to assist or share a foundation of your hacked WCF project solution so that yet another unicorn using this antient protocol doesn't have to reinvent this ugly wheel again? Or point me to any other resource that helped you put the hack in place?! I would be extremely grateful !